# Does Docker work with VirtualBox but not with KVM/QEMU?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker, kvm, qemu

[Docker can creat virtual machines to be used as nodes in swarms](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create).

The [machine drivers](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/)   contains VirualBox but no KVM/QEMU. Does it mean that

- virtual machines created by KVM/QEMU can't be used as nodes in Docker's swarm?
- Docker works  with VirtualBox but not with KVM/QEMU? (If yes, it is surprising to me, since both Docker and KVM are supported by Linux kernel natively, while VirtualBox seems less so. Is Docker a reason  to use VirtualBox instead of KVM/QEMU?)

If Docker can create virtual machines with KVM/QEMU type, then what is to be specified to `docker-machine`'s `--driver`?

Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing the docker engine with docker-machine.  Docker doesn't care about the hypervisor, and will run on KVM based VMs with no problem.

Comment: Google says: https://github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. Does docker-machine not have a KVM/QEMU argument for `--driver` option, and not have a KVM driver by default?

Comment: @StephenHarris I am not. My question again is: does docker-machine not allow  KVM/QEMU to be specified after its --driver option, by default? Why? (comparing to that it allows virtualbox to be spciified after its --driver option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why it is not very useful

As docker runs on the Linux-kernel, there is little need to run it in KVM/QEMU (Why add an extra layer of virtualisation). It is however useful to run in Virtual-box, as this allows docker on Linux, in virtual-box on Microsoft's Windows.

## Can it be done

Yes you certainly can do it manually. Just install Linux+Docker into what ever virtual machine that you want.

See also reference in @MichaelHampton's comment — [github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm](https://github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm)

Comment: (1) "As docker runs on the Linux-kernel, there is little need to run it in KVM/QEMU (Why add an extra layer of virtualisation)."  Why is there no such need? Do you not need to have several virtual machines running on a Linux machine, and each virtual machine runs some docker container? In that case, which does Docker work with,  KVM/QEMU or VirtualBox?

Comment: (2) "As docker runs on the Linux-kernel, there is little need to run it in KVM/QEMU (Why add an extra layer of virtualisation)." My question were: `docker-machine` not allow KVM/QEMU to be specified after its `--driver` option, by default? Why? (comparing to that it allows virtualbox to be spciified after its `--driver` option)

Comment: ①Docker allows you to run many containers, not just one. So you don't need another tool to run many dockers. ② I don't know, how and if. As I don't combine VMs and docker (Unless I use a virtual-machine provided by a cloud provider).